# What is the command to delete empty lines in a file using sed?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, command

- What is the `sed` command to delete empty lines in a file.
- What is the command (`sed` command?) to delete empty files in a folder?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? How do you want to achieve it? Which language? PHP?

Comment: @Fender: language: sed. Want to achieve: Remove empty lines.

Comment: For deleting empty files, you probably use `find folder -maxdepth 1 -size 0 -exec rm {} +` (or you can use `-print` and `xargs`, or better, if your `find` and `xargs` combo supports it, `-print0` and `xargs -0`) or even replace the `+` with `;` if your `find` does not support `+`, as long as speed isn't too critical.  (NB: `-maxdepth` is a GNU `find` extension over [POSIX `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Gnu find: `find directory -empty -delete` - no xargs gymnastics needed.

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2013/01/deleting-empty-lines-from-file.html

Answer (score 12):

You have to 'd' which is used to delete.

```
Ex:

 sed -i '/^$/d' test
```

-i - is used to affect the file.

^ - is a beginning of line

$ - is a end of line

d - delete if there is a empty line

I hope this will help you.

Comment: in this case ^ is the beginning of a line, $ is the end of the line. The d deletes all lines matching the prefix regular expression

Answer (score 2):

`/^$/d` should do it.

for example

```
sed -i -e "/^$/d" myfile.txt
```

if you want to do this to all the files in a folder:

```
sed -i -e "/^$/d" *
```

-i means "edit in place" without it, the file will be edited and sent to standard output. The original file will be unmodified.

Comment: you should not specify the myfile.txt.You have to use $i. `Ex:sed -i -e "/^$/d" $i`. $i having the file name.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/#.*//;/^\s*$/d' /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
```